# How to make a Text which will scroll its content automatically horizontally while content is longer than size in android jetpack compose? Like Marque

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, marquee, android-compose-textfield

How to make a Text or TextField which will scroll its content automatically horizontally while content is longer than size in android jetpack compose?
Like horizontal Marque

I know that I can use:

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f).horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
```

but it doesn't scroll automatically, I have to drag it.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [`1.4.0-alpha04`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.4.0-alpha04) you can use the [**`basicMarquee`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).basicMarquee(kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.MarqueeAnimationMode,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.MarqueeSpacing,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) modifier:

```
// Marquee only animates when the content doesn't fit in the max width.

Column(Modifier.width(100.dp)) {
    Text("hello world hello world hello world",
        modifier = Modifier.basicMarquee())
}
```

[image]

Comment: which library I have to updated to 1.4.0-alpha04?

Comment: @Cipri The [compose foundation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.4.0-alpha04) library